# Questions on how to define quotient topology on space of lattices

Tags: general-topology

For the following two questions:

1) Let $X$ be the Cartesian plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $Y$ be the lattice of points $(m,n)$ in $X$ with both $m$ and $n$ integers.  Describe the quotient topology on $X/Y$.  What topological object is $X/Y$?

2) Let $v$ and $w$ be linearly independent vectors in the plane.  Consider the lattice $L=\{mv+nw: m,n\in \mathbb{Z}\}$.  This describes a lattice, and we may consider $\mathbb{R}^2/L$.  What sort of topological object is this quotient?  Can you describe its topology?

I am a bit confused and I am wondering if someone from the community can clarify it for me.  I am not sure if the two questions are asking for the quotient spaces or the quotient topology.  My understanding of the definition of the quotient topology are as follows:

> **Definition:**  Let $(X,U)$ be a topological space and let $Y$ be any set.  Suppose that $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a surjective mapping.  Then the collection of subsets 
>   $$\tau_{f}=\{{G\subset Y:f^{-1}(G) \text{ is open in } X\}}$$
>   is a topology on $Y$ called the quotient topology induced on $Y$ by $f$.  When $Y$ is endowed with such a quotient topology, then it is called a quotient space of $X$, and the inducing map $f$ is called a quotient map.

For both (1) and (2), I am not certain if it is asking for what the quotient topology is or what the quotient space is.  Also, when is asking for the topological object, is it asking for what the quotient space is?  If it is asking for the quotient topology, what mappings $f$ can I use for both questions as well as, how can I describe their open sets for their quotient topology.
But if it is asking for the quotient spaces for both of them, can I definie the following relations for the respective in both questions.  The equivalence relation being: $(m,n)\sim(m',n')$ iff $m-m' \in \mathbb{Z}, n-n' \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The answer depends on what kind of a quotient is desired. Algebraically the sensible quotient would be the quotient group corresponding to the equivalence relation: $xv+yw\sim x'v+y'w$ if and only if $x-x',y-y'\in\Bbb{Z}$. The resulting quotient is interesting also topologically, and is homeomorphic to a torus. But, in topology it also makes sense to think of  $\Bbb{R}^2/L$ as gotten from simply identifying all the points in $L$ to a single point, *leaving the points on other cosets as they are*.

Comment: (cont'd) I'm not an expert, so I don't know for sure what the wordings of your questions suggest, but it may be that in (1) the intended space is the latter and in (2) we get a torus with a view of putting a topology on the quotient group.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen thank you for your response.  I think it probably has something to do with the torus.  Or at least one of the question does.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thank you for your editing help.  :)

Comment: 1 and 2 are homeomorphic.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Can I ask how i can show that 1 and 2 are homeomorphic.  Thank you.